# LCAP and VLan on FreeNAS box

Tags: networking, vlan, network-attached-storage, truenas, bonding

I can not seem to get the FreeNAS GUI to come up when I try to use link aggregation. I have been googling for days and I am totally lost as to where I am going wrong. I will list the equipment I have down below.

**Equipment**

1.Ubiquiti EdgeRouter 6P

2.Netgear GS752TP 52 port switch

3.Custom-built FreeNAS box with Intel X540T2 network card

**My Goal**

I would like to set up LCAP over VLAN 45 on a really weird network range so that when our staff logs in over the VPN the chance that the network range will overlap with the network they are on is small. I want to use LCAP so that it will balance when the staff is sending or accessing large files. Below I will show pictures of all of my settings and where I am stuck

**My Current setup**

The two network cables from the intel card in the FreeNAS box are plugged into the switch on ports 45 and 47 on the Netgear switch.

So far I have configured the switch so that channel 1 with LAG id of 1 is in LACP for "LAG Type" and "Active Ports" are g45, g47, and "LAG State" is up.

[image: LAG setup 1]
[image: LAG setup 2]

Then for the VLAN I made a VLAN with an ID of 45 and then in the VLAN Membership I Tagged port 2 and LAG 1. I Tagged port 2 because that is the port that is going back to the router.
[image]
[image]

Then on the FreeNAS box, I obviously don't have a GUI to take screenshots of, but it states that I am at the address of 172.16.213.100. I can even go to the terminal and type in `ifconfig` and it will confirm it.

The steps I took, were to configure Link Aggregation, then configure VLAN Interface, then Configure Network Interfaces and type in the ipv4 address for interface vLan45.

[image]
[image]
[image]

For the router, I have configured the VLAN properly, as before I tried to set it up with LCAP it was able to be seen over the VLAN, that Is how I know my firewall rules should let everything go through.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is everything I have done and this is where I am stuck. Is there something I am missing or have miss configured? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this worked, and maybe this solution will help someone else out. If you know why this worked please tell me in the comments, because it does not make sense to me.

**Solution**

I am only using 2 ports on my network card, and I still have a network port on my motherboard. I plugged a network cable into that port and got on the CLI of the FreeNAS box and just configured that network port on the motherboard to be apart of my main network.

The moment I did that, my VLAN/LCAP started to work and I can now access the web GUI from the IP-address that is desired.

Again I have no clue as to why it worked, but hopefully, this can help someone else out. that is having the same issue.